# A verb that's used before "a presentation"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I remember my biology class when I had to __ my very first
> presentation.

Some verbs I have managed to guess are *perform*, *give*, and *make*. However, I don't know which is more appropriate. For clarity, it's not a preparation i.e. at that time I was standing in front of my friends and ready to start the presentation.

Comment: *make*, *give*, and, also, *do* are the words often used with *presentation*.

Comment: Perform does not sound right but as @AndrewTobilko states _make_ or _give_ were correct guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambridge dictionary [mentions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presentation#:%7E:text=give/make/do%20a%20presentation):

> give/make/do a presentation

Of these options I prefer "give".  "Make" is possible, but overlaps with the preparation of a slideshow.  And "do" is a rather generic verb, which I'd avoid if a more specific verb is available.

So "give a presentation".